# OGRE error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost, compiler-errors, ogre

I'm trying to get some OGRE sample to compile in VS 2013 but I keep getting the same error no matter what I do:

`error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class boost::system::error_category const & __cdecl boost::system::system_category(void)"`

The OGRE SDK comes with the boost library. Unfortunatly it is not compatible with VS2013 so I've downloaded the last version compiled using VS2013. You can find it [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost-binaries/1.55.0-build2/)

The "additional Include Directories" and "additional Library Directories" are properly setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error state that you are using a symbol that is **declared**, but not **implemented**, `boost::system::error_category` is a method of boost, that various libraries use when managing errors, it belong to the **system** library, the implementation of this method is in **[BOOST_ROOT]\boost\libs\system\src\error_code.cpp**.

The most probably cause is that your are including the *OGRE's library* or part of the library that include some *boost's libraries* that use this method.

A lot of libraries from boost are header only, but this specific library **system** are not, it need compilation of this *.cpp*: two possible fixes are compiling an **.LIB or .DLL** from boost (see [Prepare to Use a Boost Library Binary](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#id34) for more info about this) and using this in your project (could be better if you would be using a lot of libraries from boost that are not header only) or the most easy fix: *including the `error_code.cpp` file in your project and compiling again.*

Comment: Thanks a lot, I've included **error_code.cpp** in my project and the error disappeared. Now I still don't understand why it didn't worked with the included **libboost_system-blablabla.lib**.

Comment: Most probably some problem compiling boost with VS2013, the common way of compiling boost is using their build manager (bjam previously, now is named b2, see the link posted), i think there some way using CMake too (that could generate VS projects from the CMake files, but is not totally supported yet)

Comment: You were right all the way. I switched to using `libboost_system-vc110.lib` with VS2012 and it works. No need to include the `error_code.cpp` file in my project anymore. Thx